# Blazor Date Input as Text

Tags: html, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

The current control i'm having is this:

[image]

```
@inherits FloatingLabelControl<DateTime?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="input-data">
        <input type="date"
               hasvalue="@HasValueProp"
               format-value="@Format"
               @bind-value="Value"
               required="@RequiredProp" />
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <label>@LabelText</label>
    </div>
</div>

@code{

public string HasValueProp = "";

[Parameter]
public string Format { get; set; }


private DateTime? _value;
[Parameter]
public override DateTime? Value
{
    get => base.Value;
    set
    {

        base.Value = value;
        if (base.Value.HasValue)
            HasValueProp = "yes";
        else
            HasValueProp = "no";
    }
}


}
```

However when it is viewed in mobile, the input becomes a date picker.
I have to scroll it to certain year. and it is not user friendly.

[image]

Is there a way to ignore the hide/datepicker for input(type=date) in mobile mode?

Answer (score 0):

When you use default HTML controls, it's up to the browser to decide how it presents them to the client.  Fighting with Chrome or Firefox is a good way to upset ourselves.  (For me, it was trying to make checkbox inputs display bigger)

Could you please try

```
<input type="date"
               hasvalue="@HasValueProp"
               format-value="@Format"
               @bind-value="Value"
               required="@RequiredProp" 
               onClick="event.preventDefault()"
/>
```

and let me know if **onClick="event.preventDefault()"** helps?  (Be sure to try it on all browsers though)

(Sorry, I'm at work so I can't test it right now)

Comment: hi doesn't work on mobile. It is still using the datepicker

Comment: I've had a lot of grief with stuff like this.  And the worst thing is that if you use standard html controls in a way that works today, there's no guarantee that a major browser will implement the control in the same way tomorrow.  HOWEVER, one of the very nice things about Blazor is how easy it is to create custom  components.  I recommend making a custom date picker using only text inputs, dropdowns, or whatever YOU want.  Blazor has great form validation, so it should be easy to ensure that you get the exact input that you want.

Comment: thanks for the advice Sir Benny, looks like i have no other choice but to have a custom logic that will convert/validate the string to date time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to find an alternative solution, as per bennyboy1973 adviced me to create a custom logic. I have integrated this plugin from RobinHerbots (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) that will an input[type=text] without the datepicker.

The below code are my final solution:

[image]